# How to graph a seaborn lineplot more specifically

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Given a mass DataFrame `df`:

```
year        count
1980        -23
1980        -4
1981        10
1982        0
1982        4
...
2007        27
2008        0
2008        0
2009        -7
2009        5
```

with values sorted by `year` first, and then `count`. (the values displayed are arbitrarily changed)

I'd like to visualize how the `count` distributes differently as `year` increases, which can be most effectively displayed by a percentile plot. However, since my data are given in a DataFrame, I thought a more feasible (and quite frankly, simpler) way would be to use `seaborn.lineplot`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[16,12])

plt.axhline(y=0, color='black', linestyle='dotted')
sns.lineplot(x="year", y="count", ax=ax, data=df, color='red')
```

which returns:

[image]

This graph somewhat serves a purpose, although I would like the display to have more variabilities than just a single percentile gradient. (A good example would be a figure below with 10 percentile gradients, copied from this link: [Using percentiles of a timeseries to set colour gradient in Python's matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53071379/using-percentiles-of-a-timeseries-to-set-colour-gradient-in-pythons-matplotlib))

[image]

I'd like to know if there is a way to achieve such detailed graphing using `seaborn.lineplot`, and if not, if there is a way to do so from a `pandas` DataFrame data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have generated the first confidence interval or just the line, you can use matplotlib, as shown in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59747313/how-to-plot-confidence-interval-in-python) to create multiple confidence interval.

The other option is to plot on the same figure using `sns.lineplot`, though I think seaborn is not meant for this. Using dataset `flights` as an example, first we plot the median or mean line:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

flights = sns.load_dataset("flights")
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

sns.lineplot(data=flights, x="year", y="passengers",ax=ax,ci=None,color="black")
```

Then we set up a color palette and keep adding the bands without the lines (setting linestyle = ''):

```
cm = sns.color_palette("Blues",9)

for ix,ci in enumerate(range(10,90,10)):
    sns.lineplot(data=flights, x="year", y="passengers",
                 ci = ci,
                 ax=ax,linestyle='',
                 hue = ci,palette={ci:cm[ix]})
```

Gives something like this:

[image]